# Coil Gun Schematic

Tags: power-supply, transformer, schematics, electromagnetism, coil

I have a question. I have been looking at making a Coil gun lately and i had an idea for a simple one. Just need to know if it would work. Basically:
Battery-->Switch-->Diode-->Transformer-->Coil

For my Coil I am using a coil from a Pinball Machine Flipper. Just An Idea for makers of a coil gun.[image]

Comment: DC through a transformer?

Comment: yes why is that?

Comment: Should I Convert To AC?

Comment: By "work" what do you mean?

Comment: Would It Generate the proper electromagnetic field to launch the projectile through the center of the coil.

Comment: That depends on things that a schematic could never encapsulate. I think you need to google how a coil gun works. It's like showing the schematic of a radio receiver and asking if it will tune to 99.8 MHz without any details of the coils used or the local oscillator frequency.

Comment: Essentaly it SHOULD work. My real question should have been, will the transformer replace the capacitors (220VDC)

Comment: No, a transformer is very different from a capacitor!

Comment: It is now an unclear question because a transformer cannot provide the massive lump of current into the coil and the OP believes that "essentially is should work". This is contradictory.

Comment: An transformer Transforms a low voltage to a high voltage or vise versa. An Electromagnet is just voltage going through a coil of wire. More Voltage=More Magnetism. I though it should work but am unsure if it can provide a substantial load to move  a projectile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle that will work, but probably not well. Efficient coil gun drive requires the coil to maintain current while the projectile is accelerating, and only cut the current when the projectile is in the coil. If the current persists after the projectile exits the coil it will act to decellerate the projectile, which does defeat the purpose of the whole thing. Your circuit (and it needs resistances to model coil resistance and the transformer - as it stands if you try to run a simulation it will produce infinite current in both the transformer and the coil) will produce a fixed pulse width. Is this too short, too long, or just right? No way to tell.